# Improving efficiency of core data duplicate verification

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a method in my Database class that verifies whether the given value exists in a entity or not. Everything is working perfectly fine except that I am trying to optimise this method. Can you guys let me know whether this code can be further optimised?

```
- (NSUInteger)recordAlreadyExists:(NSString*)string forEntity:(NSString*)entityName forKey:(NSString*)key
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [Helper generateNewContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
    [newContext setUndoManager:nil];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
        //NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%K LIKE \"%@\"", key, string];//,key,string];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", key, string];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSUInteger resultsCount = [newContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if(resultsCount)
        return resultsCount;
    return 0;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

- Test for exact equality `"%K == %@"` in your predicate, instead of `"%K LIKE %@"`.

`LIKE` compares using simple wildcards (`*`, `?`), so that for example searching for "J*" will also find an entry "John". This is slower than testing for equality and probably not intended.

- Create an index for the attribute.

If you have to search for some attributes very fast, you can set the "Indexed" property in the Core Data inspector for that attribute.

*Remark:* Note that `countForFetchRequest:` returns `NSNotFound` if there is an error executing the request, so you should also check for that return value.

Comment: Thank you @Martin. I did see a marked improvement in performance :)